# Using pre-built Python class and methods within my class

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

I am trying to understand how Python implements OO. I’m trying to understand how I can use an existing class within my class – so as much of the processing is hidden as possible from the programmer.
The exercise I have created is to write a Class Rect that can be used to create an object that has two attributes : len and wid and (somehow) will “contain” another object – which I will call “stylus”.
My idea is when I instantiate an object of class Rect, I will pass the length and width of the rectangle and a “stylus” created by

```
stylus = turtle.Turtle()
```

Say the Rect object created is rect_obj, then I want to define a method, draw_rect, in Rect that will draw the rectangle. My code attempt is below (*) (which of course doesn’t work).

(*)

```
class Rect:
    def __init__(self,rect_len,rect_wid,stylus_in):
        self.len = rect_len
        self.wid = rect_wid
        self.stylus = stylus_in

    #
    def draw_rect(self,stylus):

        self.stylus.forward(len)
        self.stylus.right(90)

    # class Square(Rect):
    def __init__(self,side_len):
        self.len =  side_len
        self.wid =  side_len
    import turtle stylus = turtle.Turtle() 

rect_obj = Rect(int(5),int(4),stylus)  

stylus = turtle.Turtle() 

print(rect_obj.len)  


print(rect_obj.wid)  

rect_obj.draw_rect(stylus)
```

I’m trying to understand how I code the Python so I hide this processing and all that needs to be written is something like:

```
rect_obj.draw_rect(stylus)
```

Now, when I run my code it fails in turtle.py with following error messages:

```
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized *** 5 4 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Clive\Desktop\temp_OOP_turtle.py", line
27, in <module>
    rect_obj.draw_rect(stylus)   File "C:\Users\Clive\Desktop\temp_OOP_turtle.py", line 12, in draw_rect
    self.stylus.forward(len)   File "C:\Users\Clive\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py",
line 1637, in forward
    self._go(distance)   File "C:\Users\Clive\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py",
line 1604, in _go
    ende = self._position + self._orient * distance   File "C:\Users\Clive\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py",
line 257, in __mul__
    return Vec2D(self[0]*other, self[1]*other) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Is there anyway I can fix my Python so the code for moving the turtle is provided in a method inside Rect class?

I can get my stylus to draw a rectangle if I put the code currently in draw_rect at the “level” of my main routine (see end **) but that doesn't hide the code that draws the rectangle.

(**) Code that will draw a 50 x 70 rectangle but **outside** the class Rect:
import turtle

```
smart = turtle.Turtle()
for i in range(2):
    smart.forward(50)
    smart.right(90)
    smart.forward(70)
    smart.right(90)
```

Comment: in `draw_rect` you have this mistake: `self.stylus.forward(len)` should be `self.stylus.forward(self.len)`

Comment: @ShadowRanger - your correction to my code worked. Can you post as an answer and I will accept?

Comment: @CliveLong: Uhh... I didn't make any corrections to your code, I just replaced blockquote formatting with code block formatting. Did you mean topsail's correction?

Comment: @topsail Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: This is such a small error, I will just vote to close as a typo. But thinking on it, the error makes sense now - `len` vs. `self.len` means that python was interpreting `len` by itself as the built-in `len` function.

Comment: @topsail Your correction has given me a better understanding of when to use "self." Maybe I was implicitly assuming that the "self." at the start of the expression somehow propagated to "len" - which it didn't - and now I know to look out for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comment by @topsail:

in `draw_rect` you have this mistake: `self.stylus.forward(len)` should be `self.stylus.forward(self.len)`